Transactions hanging
Trying to send any transaction from my wallet and they are all hanging. As a minimal case I'm trying to send 0.01 sol from the wallet to another and even that just hangs. I am using the solana cli tool.

Yes that does thanks. Wish the title was better so it's more easily searchable though.

Ended up re-submitting the transaction at midnight and it worked. I guess the network was just backed up.
For anyone else with the same issue, wait until it's less busy or set a priority fee.
